# xmonad responds only to the default keybindings

Tags: haskell, configuration, xmonad

I'm trying to configure xmonad to work as I want it to in Ubuntu 14. Since I'm not familiar with Haskell's syntax, I took 3 configuration files and removed what I didn't like and kept what I liked. I had a lot of errors, but once I resolved them all, it didn't seem to work. 
Xmonad notices only the default keybindings but recognized the other parts of my file (like xmobar). Each config on its own worked fine.
My `xmonad.hs` file is here:
http://pastebin.com/knB2kc8H

I'll appreciate it if you take a look and tell me what's wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Which key bindings are not working as you expect?

Comment: @JeffBurka Oh, it seems I was wrong. The key bindings it notices are the ones I left as default. It seems like it just ignored my config file (But only in the keys part, xmobar works fine and I launch it from here). Is this a known issue? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug this, pick a key binding that doesn't seem to work, and do the following:

1. Map that key to something that does work (i.e., duplicate the key
   binding that you used for another, working key).
2. If that works, then
   you know that Xmonad can "see" the key.
3. Now map that key to what you
   want, but send any errors to a file. E.g.,

   .... unsafeSpawn "scrot -e 'mv $f ~/Pictures' > /home/me/errors.log 2>&1")
4. See what errors you get, and deal with them.

I notice that you use `~` in some of your paths. I seem to recall that I had trouble with that. In my own xmonad.hs, I use full paths everywhere.